# XCode 4.2 opens with no toolbar, project navigator

Tags: xcode4

I was using XCode 4.2 for a bit and I hit a wrong set of keystroke (I will assume command - something) and all the sudden XCode main window went away. I had no clue how to restore that but fortunately I had a source file opened in a separate window so I restored the toolbar and project navigator.

Now when I relaunch XCode, it never launches with the toolbar and project navigator again.
I have to reset them manually each time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For that sake of helping out future readers this is the clearer explanation of how to fix this issue:

XCode will open the project with the interface configured the same way as the last file that was opened. If your interface is opening with the toolbar and project navigator minimized it means that you double clicked a file and opened it in its own window. XCode thinks that this was the last file opened so it uses this as the default.

To resolve: reconfigure your window by right clicking on the top of the window and selecting "show toolbar" then open whichever panels you prefer to have open.  Then make sure there are no other windows associated with that project open. Close XCode and reopen.  Voila!

Comment: xCode is so dumb sometimes. I could understand this for an individual file it should be able to recognize a project file and open it with the whole toolbar.

Comment: That answer didn't work for me. But I found that I got those problems only on specific projects so I deleted my `project_name.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/user_name.xcuserdatad` folder and reopened my the project workspace, all is fine again. Although you'll lose all your breakpoints etc.

Comment: Thank you, Jens Kohl! This happened to me after removing CocoaPods from a project - removing the xcuserdata fixed the project again!

Answer (score 2):

doesnt work for me.
Im activating "icon and text" to see the top toolbar of xcode.
than doing something and closing.and after reopening no voila.
I have to re-activate "icon and text" to see top toolbar each time of opening my project.

Answer (score 1):

By default - you open a new tab with command + T, but that can be changed. The way you close a tab is just like any other window in Mac OS, with command + W.

If you need to open the file tree on the left, or one of the other 6 views in the left panel, you can toggle by pressing the first segment button on the "View" category, situated on the top right of the Xcode window (Next to the Organizer button).

Comment: Command W sounds like a good bet, but how do I get my window to stay that way after a restart? I don't want to keep pressing those keys (which btw I don't see cause the toolbar is not there).

Comment: No, you don't have to press it again. Xcode remembers your preferences and opens the way you left closed it.

Comment: hmmm it didn't first thing this morning (had to reboot my mac) but after I read your response and tried again, it worked. I think it may have been cause I was using "Reveal in Project Navigator" instead of "View | Navigator | Show Project Navigator". Thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is still an issue with Xcode 7 (7.2.1 in my case). You've got two options:

1. Follow the instructions in Ian Hoar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523622/408150).
2. Delete Xcode's `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`:

   1. Close the project within Xcode
   2. Navigate to your project via the Terminal
   3. `rm project_name.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/user_name.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`
   4. Reopen the project in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 9**, from the top bar, right click and pick any

[image]